# extjs set x relative to the parent panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, position

I have an ExtJs Component (I've named it "arrow") inside a panel which is inside another panel in body.

```
{
xtype:'panel',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'panel', 
        height: 10,
        width: '100%',
        layout: 'absolute',
        items: [{
                xtype: 'component',// top arrow
                cls: 'irc_pc',
                x: 200,
                id:'arrow'
            }]

    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        width: '100%',
        bodyPadding:5,
        flex: 1,
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'center',
            pack: 'center'
        },   
        height: '100%',
        cls: 'big-box',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        bodyStyle: 'background-color:#222',

    }
]
}
```

css:

```
.irc_pc {
  border-bottom: 10px solid #222;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

view:
[image]

I want to handle the relative distance "a" not "b". distance "b" is absolute. the first adjustment of "x" property of the component is correct, but next in the console when I try to getX() or setX() It does not work correctly!

```
ar = Ext.getCmp('arrow');
ar.getX(); // outs 545
ar.setX(600); // sets the distance "b"! I don't like it.
```

please help!

Comment: usually to draw those arrows use the CSS psedu-code :after, why didn't you do it?

Comment: I necessarily need to set x !

Comment: can you add [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com)?